# Import .csv to knowledge using Import Wizard

Tags: record-type, knowledge, csv, data-import-wizard

I am trying to import .csv file to SalesForce Knowledge.

**First Question :**  I cannot find the "Knowledge" option in "Custom Objects". When I goto Data Import Wizard,I should be able to see this. Am I missing some permission or setting? Please guide...

[image: Import Knowledge Custom Object]

**Second question:** Did anyone try importing knowledge using this wizard? I have a .csv file which contains the fields similar to the ones in my "Record Type". I want to import my .csv and load few KBs using this wizrd. Please guide me here as I am completely new to SF.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to select `Import Articles` instead of `Data Import Wizard` option from setup menu.

Quoting from [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_article_importer_04zip.htm&type=0):

> From Setup, enter Import Articles in the Quick Find box, then select
>   Import Articles.

Salesforce reference document: [Import Existing Information into Salesforce Knowledge](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_article_importer.htm&type=0&language=en_US)

Comment: I want to use data import wizard , instead of creating a .zip file with .html, .properties etc. I can see the option to import knowledge data in my trailhead salesforce instance. I cannot see the same in another instance.